# git svn "unable to chdir up to '.'"

Tags: git, git-svn

I use a local git with a SVN remote server, everything works fine but after my last reboot I get the following error with everything related to git svn.

```
unable to chdir up to '.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is a matter of bad environment variable setting when boot. 
Reboot solved the issue.

Comment: Given that the OP started getting this error after rebooting (according to the question), I don't see how suggesting a reboot could help the OP.